# Why don't we say "hamelech hagadol"?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, aseres-yemei-teshuva

During the 10 days of T'shuva, we change certain wording from "el" to "melech" in the Shmoneh Esrei (and Magen Avot). But in the beginning of the Amida, we say "ha-el hagadol hagibor v'hanora". Why don't we, as we focus on God's kingship, change that to "hamelech…"?

[In the next like, we say "el elyon" but I read (possibly in an Artscroll or a Koren siddur) that that formulation, preceding "gomel chasadim" is supposed to be about God's mercy so it wouldn't make sense to change it.]

Comment: It's a Pasuk https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.10.17

Comment: Well, it is 4 words from a pasuk. We quote more of a pasuk elsewhere and yet change a word of the pasuk.

Comment: 1) this is specifically intended as a direct quote(megillah 25a) 2) if you mean קונה שמים וארץ then indeed that is a Chiddush and indeed some old Nusach had the original and that's why it survived in Mein Sheva

Comment: I find it interesting that none of the local siddurim which provide citations for p'sukim have a reference for that phrase but I was thinking more along the lines of "yotzer ohr...et ha kol". It just seems that the fact that it is from a pasuk doesn't automatically invalidate changing a word.

Comment: Depends if you're quoting or alluding. Just like citing sources here on Mi Yodeya.